# RabbitMQ Consumer/Reciever not working in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmq-c

I am currently working with the rabbitMQ server, As when i try working in c# console application, the publish exchange working and successfully save in the server and the message will lively appear in the console but when i apply my source code in the C# windows form, it will not get all the message sent by the publisher. I put the method in the constructor event but no happen at all it will not receive any message.

Please see source code below

```
using Publisher;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Consumer
{
    public partial class Consumer : Form
    {

        private EventingBasicConsumer consumer;
        ConnectionFactory factory;
        public Consumer()
        {
            factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = Definition.HOSTNAME };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: Definition.EXCHANGE, type: ExchangeType.Fanout);

                var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
                channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                                  exchange: Definition.EXCHANGE,
                                  routingKey: "");




                Debug.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for Exchange ARexchange.");
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (sender, ea) =>
                {
                   var body = ea.Body;
                   var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                   Debug.WriteLine(" [x] {0}", message);
                 };
                channel.BasicConsume(
                                queueName,
                                 autoAck: false,
                                 consumer: consumer);
            }

            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void Consumer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void setExchange()
        {
            lblExchange.Text = Definition.EXCHANGE;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Form serving any purpose here?

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey i updated my source code, for testing purposes i just Write down Debug.Writeline in my code to test if it will return the message. The form have no serving yet here.

Comment: Well, the form constructor isn't a place where you can hold persistent variables, like `connection` and `channel`.  Once the constructor finishes executing, those variables vanish.

Comment: Ah yup i tried to put it in the constructor to test if it work but sad to say it didn't work, i tried also put into the form_load method but same noting happened .

Comment: @RobertHarvey when i create a console application same with the above source code it will receive message and working properly but when i apply it on the windows form application i didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

```
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
```

When those `using` statements exit, the channel and connection will be closed. Change your code to save those as instance variables in the `Consumer` class. Then, when your form exits, you can clean up those two instances.

If you provide your code in a repository that can be cloned, compiled and run people could assist you by submitting pull requests to improve your code.